# sql count with inner join

Tags: sql, count, inner-join

I have a table for absentees, and that table am storing the studentids of those who have been absent.

From this table I had to find total presentees and total absentees, for this I just joined the Sections table which contains the maximum capacity of particular Section.

For this my query was

```
select COUNT(Attendance.studentid) as Absentees
        ,Sections.Max-count(studentid) as Presentees
from Attendance
inner join Students
on students.StudentId=Attendance.StudentId
inner join Sections
on Sections.CourseId=students.CourseId
group by Sections.Max
```

Its working fine, the same way how can I find the gender wise presentees/absentees......gender column is in Students table, can anyone give me some idea, thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add the gender column to your `select ...` columns and the `group by`, you'll end up with one row for each gender:

```
select COUNT(Attendance.studentid) as Absentees,
       Sections.Max-count(studentid) as Presentees,
       Students.Gender as Gender
from Attendance
inner join Students
on Students.StudentId=Attendance.StudentId
inner join Sections
on Sections.CourseId=Students.CourseId
group by Sections.Max, Students.Gender
```